# How do I return query results without the 'sum' column label?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have the following formula in Google Sheets:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(C13&"!$C$5:F"), 
  "SELECT sum(F) WHERE D ='" &$E$12 &"'
   AND C >= date'" &TEXT($G$4,"yyyy-mm-dd") &"'
   AND C <= date'" &TEXT($K$4,"yyyy-mm-dd") &"'")
```

The formula returns the correct result but it includes the  label 'sum' as the first row.

How do I get the result without the label?

Example Results

| Current |  | Desired |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sum |  | 13916333 |
| 13916333 |  |  |

[image: How to remove this sum label using that query]

Answer (score 1):

Add `LABEL Sum(F) ''` immediately before the closing quotation mark `"` of  the QUERY function's `query` argument.

[QUERY Function Syntax](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

```
=QUERY(data, query, [headers])
```

In your formula, your `query` argument is:

```
"SELECT sum(F) WHERE D ='" &$E$12 &"'
   AND C >= date'" &TEXT($G$4,"yyyy-mm-dd") &"'
   AND C <= date'" &TEXT($K$4,"yyyy-mm-dd") &"'"
```

After adding the `LABEL` clause to the end of the  `query` your formula would now be:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(C13&"!$C$5:F"), 
  "SELECT sum(F) WHERE D ='" &$E$12 &"'
   AND C >= date'" &TEXT($G$4,"yyyy-mm-dd") &"'
   AND C <= date'" &TEXT($K$4,"yyyy-mm-dd") &"' LABEL Sum(F) '' ")
```

Comment: The post is two years old. Given changes in function options, I likely wouldn't even do it this way anymore. So whatever you did... I'm sure it's fine.