# Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

With reference to the question [how to remove sum label from query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/161860/how-to-remove-sum-label-from-query), I have a similar situation.

Where would I put the `LABEL sum(E)` in this formula?

```
=if(($B2="weekday"), ifna(QUERY('Base Data'!$A:$G, "select sum(E) where B = '"&D$1&"' and G = '"&$A2&"'",0),"") , "")
```

Comment: Simon, my apologies! I'm aware that you're new to the site, originally posted this question as an answer, and that answer was closed during the review process (question posted as an answer).  You deserve credit for following the advice in the close reason to the letter. You posted a new question referencing the other one. Now it's been closed as a duplicate. The other question has been updated and I hope that addresses any confusion you may have had.  Follow its instructions while looking at your QUERY separately from the rest of your formula. Please continue contributing to this community.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried adding in the LABEL statement in various places but I can't just find the right place that doesn't cause an error. I'm pretty new to Query / Select and learning on the fly. Are you able to point me in the right direction please.

Comment: This is the QUERY in your formula: `QUERY('Base Data'!$A:$G, "select sum(E) where B = '"&D$1&"' and G = '"&$A2&"'",0)` and LABEL goes inside the `"SELECT..."` before the end: `QUERY('Base Data'!$A:$G, "select sum(E) where B = '"&D$1&"' and G = '"&$A2&"' LABEL sum(E) ''",0)` Remember to include a space before  Label.  If you still get an error post the error message and I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```
=IF($B2="weekday", IFNA(QUERY('Base Data'!$A:$G, "SELECT sum(E) WHERE B = '"& D$1& "' AND G = '"& $A2& "' LABEL sum(E) ''", 0)),)
```

Equivalent but line breaks added to assist visually:

```
=IF($B2="weekday", 
  IFNA(
    QUERY('Base Data'!$A:$G, 
      "SELECT sum(E) 
       WHERE B = '"& D$1& "' AND G = '"& $A2& "'
       LABEL sum(E) '' ", 0)),)
```

## Explanation

1. The IFNA-wrapped QUERY function in your original formula is the IF function's **value_if_true** argument:

   ```
   =IF(logical_test, IFNA(QUERY), value_if_false)
   ```
2. QUERY follows function follows the syntax:

   ```
   =QUERY(data, query_text, [headers])
   ```

   Excluding its **data** argument, **`'Base Data'!$A:$G`**, and **headers**, **`0`**, what remains is the **query_text**:

   ```
   =QUERY('Base Data'!$A:$G, "SELECT sum(E) 
       WHERE B = '"& D$1& "' AND G = '"& $A2& "'", 0)
   ```

   and your **`LABEL sum(E)`** would go at the end of it

   ```
   "select sum(E) where B = '"& D$1& "' and G = '"& $A2&"' LABEL sum(E) '' "
   ```

## Additional Notes:

1. In Sheets, IF function doesn't require a value if you want to return a blank, just include the comma without a value:

   ```
   =IF(1=2, valu_if_true, )
   ```
2. IFNA doesn't require a value or a comma if you want to return a blank:

   ```
   =IFNA(#N/A)
   ```